# How to remove something common from each row of an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, database, string, csv, timestamp

I have an excel sheet with two columns. One of the columns is the time column.
It has over 10000 rows. The format of the time is: '2018-07-18 05:00:00+0530'.
The '+0530' is present in each row. I want to remove that from each row of the sheet. How should I do that?
​

Comment: Find that text and replace it with nothing? (Ctrl+F).

Comment: I have tried that. It removes the entire string with ######

Comment: Widen the column. You'll see that Excel has now converted your *time-that-looks-like-a-string* to an actual time. You can apply formatting as needed.

Comment: It has changed to something like this: 2018-07-18 05:00

Comment: The last :00 is missing

Comment: ^ Change the number format to "reapply" it.

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **C**, in **D1** enter:

```
=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-5)
```

and copy downward.

If you attempt to edit the data "in-place", you may end up also re-formatting it.

[image]

*(this assumes the single quotes are in your question, but not in your data.)*